# Searching for a character in an array by incrementing a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

So the function I declared doesn't seem to working as intended, and even so, I don't think that's the proper way to compare characters by incrementing the *pointer*, so I'm generally lost here. To be honest, pointers have always confused me and I really need to learn how to use them if I am going to get better at C. Thanks anyone for any help!

Here's the code I have, and if this helps, the purpose of the program is for you to enter a line of text, enter a single character to search in that line of text, and then find those characters using CharIsAt. (Will add the following later) the values stored in "found" will then be printed as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 41
int CharIsAt(char *pStr,char ch,int loc[],int mLoc);
int main(void){
    char array[SIZE],search;
    int found[SIZE],chars;
    printf("Enter a line of text(empty line to quit): ");
    while (fgets(array,SIZE, stdin)!=NULL && array[0]!='\n')
    {
        printf("Enter a character to search: ");
        search=getchar();
        chars=CharIsAt(array,search,found,SIZE);
    }
    return 0;
}
int CharIsAt(char *pStr,char ch,int loc[],int mLoc){
    //Searches for ch in *pStr by incrementing a pointer to access
    //and compare each character in *pStr to ch.
    int i,x;
    for (i=0;i<mLoc;i++){
        if (strcmp(pStr[i],ch)==0){
            //Stores index of ch's location to loc
            loc[i]=pStr[i];
            x++;
        }
    }
    //Returns the number of times ch was found
    return x;
}
```

EDIT: Flipped sign around in the for loop. Now the program gives me a "stopped working" error.

Comment: `strcmp(pStr[i],ch)==0`: you don't want `strcmp` for a single character (as the name implies, it's for a string, i.e., an array of characters that is NUL terminated). Just `pStr[i] == ch` is enough to test for character equality.

Comment: `i>mLoc`: no, it's `i < mLoc` instead.

Comment: And replace `loc[i]=pStr[i]`  by `loc[i]  = i`, because `i` is the index, not the charachter at `pStr[i]`.

Comment: And indeed, with the above corrections, your code *may* work (haven't tested), but it's not what is usually meant by "incrementing a pointer" (though it can be argued that `pStr[i]` is incrementing a pointer).

Comment: @Evert, your right, thank you! After making those changes, the return value of the function seems to be a high 68 even if there is only 1 of a character that I am searching for in the line entered.

Comment: Your return value mismatch may be because you never initialize `x` (to 0); it could have a random value at the start of 67, get incremented once, and you return 68.

Comment: there are functions in the C library to perform the char search, so you only have to make a single call.  Suggest using `strchr()`  I.E. `char *foundit; if( NULL == (foundit = strchr( array, search ) ) ) { // then char not found } else { // char found at *foundit` }`